# Which is better approach to perform method only once inside a loop?

Tags: java, for-loop

I have this case, I need to perform Approve Sub Module only once after one transaction is count as successful for list of transaction.
so inside a loop I need to check if the program already perform Approve or not.
Currently I think of 2 ways to do this

1. I use isApproved value to check by updating its own value with return value from performApproveSubModule method :

   ```
   List<Transaction> transactionList = request.getTransactionList();
   boolean isApproved = false;
   for(Transaction transaction : transactionList) {
        //transaction business logic, long code

        transaction.setStatus("Success");
        //approve transacion sub module
        isApproved = performApproveSubModule(isApproved, transaction);
   }

   //method
   private boolean performApproveSubModule(boolean isApproved, Transaction transaction) {
       if(!isApproved) {
           //approve business logic

           // update isApproved value to true
           isApproved = true;
       }
       return isApproved;
   }
   ```
2. I also use isApproved value to check but I pass it as reference to update the value by using a Wrapper class:

   ```
   AtomicBoolean isApproved = new AtomicBoolean();
   for(Transaction transaction : transactionList) {
       //transaction business logic, long code

       transaction.setStatus("Success");
       //approve transacion sub module
       performApproveSubModule(isApproved, transaction);
   }

   //method
   private void performApproveSubModule(AtomicBoolean isApproved, Transaction transaction) {
       if(!isApproved.get()) {
           //approve business logic

           // update isApproved value to true
           isApproved.set(true);
       }
   }
   ```

   which one should I use?
   should I use another proper way?

Comment: Your first option seems the way to go. You can add ana optimization of not calling `performApproveSubModule` once a previous transaction is approved.

Comment: But why are you setting the status as Success even before calling the approve method?

Comment: It is because `performApproveSubModule` only need to run after a transaction is count as Successfull

Comment: Does the `//transaction business logic` has logic to determine if a transaction is successful or not? In that case `transaction.setStatus("Success")` should not apply to all transactions

Comment: yes if throw exception, it will set Failed status for that particular transaction

Comment: yes `transaction.setStatus("Success")` is not appy to all transaction,
there is catch exception code for each loop, inside catch, transaction.setStatus("Failed")